# CSS transition not working in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, css-transitions

I cant get this transition working in IE or Firefox, It looks fine in Safari and Chrome.
The opacity shows but is instant.
To me the below CSS looks right and I can't see any reason that it would work in either IE or firefox.
 
I've tried this using -ms-transition and it yields the same results, but the site uses CSS3 anyway so shouldn't need the -ms- anyway from what I've read.

Any light that can be shed would be greatly appreciated!
Ben

**CSS:**

```
.XMABAN {   
    height: 153px;  
    width: 230px;  
    background-color:rgb(127,0,25);  
    padding: 0;  
    vertical-align: top;  
}

.XMABAN a {  
    height: 153px;  
    width: 230px;  
    text-decoration:none;  
}

.XMABAN a:hover         {   
    text-decoration:none;   
}

.XMABAN img             {   
    opacity: 1;  
    transition: opacity 0.70s ease-in-out;   
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.70s ease-in-out;  
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.70s ease-in-out; 
    -o-transition: opacity 0.70s ease-in-out; 
}

.XMABAN a:hover img     {   
    opacity: 0.30;  
    transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out;  
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out;  
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out;  
    -o-transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out;  
}

.XMABAN span            {   
    position: relative;  
    left: 0%;  
    top: -62%;  
    font-weight:bold;  
    font-size:20pt;  
    color:#404040;  
    transition: color 0.70s ease-in-out;  
    -moz-transition: color 0.70s ease-in-out;  
    -webkit-transition: color 0.70s ease-in-out;  
    -o-transition: color 0.70s ease-in-out;  
}

.XMABAN a:hover span    {   
    color:#FFF0F5;  
    transition: color 0.25s ease-in-out;  
    -moz-transition: color 0.25s ease-in-out;  
    -webkit-transition: color 0.25s ease-in-out;  
    -o-transition: color 0.25s ease-in-out;  
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<tr>
    <td style="width: 33%;">
        <div class="XMABAN" style="margin: 10px 0px 5px 0px;">
            <a class="DSPI" href="online.asp">
                <img src="../images/PRM_220.jpg">
                <span>TEXT</span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: What version of IE, on a side note take a look at [prefixfree](http://leaverou.github.io/prefixfree/) to avoid having to add the vendor prefixes.

Comment: Sorry, probably helps!! I've checked in IE10 and IE9 with the same result in each.

Comment: Hmm could you recreate it in a fiddle ?

Comment: CSS Transitions are **not** supported in IE9, so it will never work in IE9. They **are** supported in IE10 (without needing a prefix), so yes that ought to work, but you should check your browser mode, because if it's in compatibility mode or quirks mode, the feature will be disabled.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2fLTU/ this is working fine in ie 10 have a look

Comment: It looks like there is something on the page it's included on that's overwriting the CSS. I had it working in all browsers for about 5mins but one refresh and it doesn't work in IE10 again! Firefox is now ok though after changing the position of the webkit. Thanks James! browser mode is definitely IE10 as well so must be something missed prior. Will continue to hunt!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CSS Transitions are [not supported in IE9 or lower](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-transitions). They are supported in IE10, however, and the CSS you've included does work correctly in IE10.

I can only assume you're using IE10 with IE9 standards to test this, which is why the transition isn't working. To change this, simply set IE's *Document Mode* to Standards:

[image: IE Demonstration]

It's also worth noting that you should always include vendor prefixing **before** the intended CSS property. Specifying `transition` before `-webkit-transition`, for instance, will tell WebKit-based browsers to use the prefixed version instead of the actual version, and there may be differences in how each are handled. Change your CSS to:

```css
-moz-transition: ...;
-webkit-transition: ...;
-o-transition: ...;
transition: ...;
```