# CSS transition fade background image does not work in IE and Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've made a simple slider using css and js, the js adds a bg-image to the header, and do a slideshow with an array of images. I also added a transition with css to the bg-image to make a sort of fade out effect, but i can't get this transition working on Edge, IE 10/11 and Firefox, it works fine in Opera and Chrome. I've tried using -moz- , -ms- transition and it still not work. I've also tried to add the transition with js but it still not works.

This is the header

```
<header id="home">
    <nav>
        <div class="riga">
            <img src="resources/img/logo.png" alt="Site- Logo" class="logo">
            <ul class="main-nav">
                <li><a href="#home">home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#informazioni">informazioni</a></li>
                <li><a href="#servizi">servizi</a></li>
                <li><a href="#lavori">lavori</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contatti">contatti</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="riga">
        <div class="messaggio">
            <h1>Test</h1>
            <p class="esp">Test <span>2</span></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

This is the css

```
header {
-webkit-transition: background-image 1s linear;
-moz-transition: background-image 1s linear;
-ms-transition: background-image 1s linear;
-o-transition: background-image 1s linear;
transition: background-image 1s linear;
background-image: url();
background-size: cover;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-position: center;
height: 100vh; }
```

This is the js

```
var images=new Array('resources/js/img/1.jpg','resources/js/img/2.jpg');
var nextimage=0;
doSlideshow();

function doSlideshow(){
    if(nextimage>=images.length){nextimage=0;}
    $('header')
    .css('background-image','url("'+images[nextimage++]+'")')
    .fadeIn(500,function(){
        setTimeout(doSlideshow,5000);
    });
 }
```

How can i solve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS transition not working in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19835498/css-transition-not-working-in-ie)

Comment: You can remove all the vendor prefixes. All browsers handle transition fine including IE back through IE10. http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-transitions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`background-image` is not an animatable property ([W3.org](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#animatable-properties)).

As you've noticed, certain browsers have implemented support for it anyway (Chrome, Safari, Opera), but you'll have to create a solution that's compatible with all the browsers you need. This is typically achieved by layering images on top of one another and fading between them with `opacity`.